# How to set a Custom url in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one web application in ASP.net MVC and I have to set a custom url instead of default url.
Url like : www.hostname.com//IEAdmin/OUser/ViewStep1/a0a765a1-21a5-47d2-8ac5-bcef10baf76c

I need url like www.hostname.com/OUser/a0a765a1-21a5-47d2-8ac5-bcef10baf76c

Is it possilbe ?

Let me know if it is possible then

Which configuration i have to set in Route.config.

Comment: What's your project structure and which MVC version are you using? URLs are created according to routing rules, typically based on controller names. Which means - **you project structure matters**. What are IEAdmin, OUser and ViewStep1? Which one is a controller, which is an action? *Depending on the MVC version* you use, you can add rules in your application startup code or routing attributes

Comment: What is your controller and action names?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a couple of additional routes, BEFORE the routes you have already defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Test",
                url: "OUser/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "OUser", action = "ViewStep1", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**PS**: you need to define this route in your area registration's route

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");                
  routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "OUser/{id}", new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" }, new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

public class RouteConfig
        {
            public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
             {
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
                routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
             }
        }