# How to specify a custom url outside of localhost for a new MVC 5 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, localhost, hostname

I've created a new MVC 5 project, and I'm trying to configure its Project URL to one that's outside of `localhost` on my local IIS, e.g. `http://alpha.domain.local`. This is easily done with a new WebForms project, but MVC 5 is providing some resistance.

I've set an entry in my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1    alpha.domain.local
```

...and I've created the site in IIS with the correct host header:

[image]
[image]

Here's my attempted project configuration:

[image]

...and the errors I get when I try to save it:

[image]
[image]

Here's what I get when I just click the `Create Virtual Directory` button (even though it already exists):

[image]

I can ping it:

[image]

I can browse to it:

[image]

I just can't point my MVC 5 project to it. MVC 5 stubbornly insists I use `localhost`, which I don't want to do. I've got some infrastructure built up that relies on these custom host names in my local IIS.

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31913444) *kind of* gets to the point, but not quite.

Like I said, this works great with a new WebForms project (VS 2019, latest build). I've been doing it for years. Now that I'm finally getting started with MVC, though, this is a bit of a wet blanket. I'm going to have to redo a bunch of stuff I can't get it working.

Is this possible? Has anyone else been able to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it. (That didn't take long!)

For some reason, an MVC 5 project won't accept a Project URL that's a subdomain, e.g. `http://alpha.domain.local`, while a WebForms project will.

I switched the URL to `http://domain.alpha` and it works. You scratch my head, I'll scratch yours. But the problem is solved. Go figure. I'm not going to try to decipher the vagaries of Microsoft.